# Print string with differently colored characters in a listview/textbox control

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, textbox, richtextbox

I would like to print the output of an algorithm (C#,.NET 4.0)in a listview control or a multiline textbox(or rich textbox) strings containing some characters which are in a different color.For example:

```
ABCAAAGGGJHHJK (whole string black)
     AHGGJI (H and I - red)
    BAJMGC  (B -green, J,M,C-red)
```

I know it is possible to change the text color & font for the whole control, but is it possible to generate it like this? Do you have any suggestions?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't easily do it with a `ListBox`, unless you're willing to draw the items manually (which is a pain). It would probably be even harder with a `TextBox`. However, you can do it with a [`RichTextBox`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.richtextbox.aspx).

```
richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
richTextBox.AppendText("ABCAAAGGGJHHJK\n");
richTextBox.AppendText("A");
richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox.AppendText("H");
richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Black;
richTextBox.AppendText("GGJ");
richTextBox.SelectionColor = Color.Red;
richTextBox.AppendText("I");
// and so on...
```

Comment: I need to create the strings character by character. I couldn't find any good example so I imagined that is not possible..

Comment: Basically I need to set the formatting for each "substring" before printing and as far as I could see the formatting is applicable for an entire string to be printed in the RichTextbOX